# Understanding RegExp for area code phone

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to understand and learn more about RegExp regarding the phone numbers, especially the area code. Mostly, the area code goes like this:
`(345)` or `345` in which the RegExp code for this is:

```
^(\()?\d{3}(\))?$
```

but is there any way to make sure that if `(345` or `345)` is typed in, then it return no match or false?

What I can understand is:

- `^ ... $` - is the beginning and the end of the string
- `()` - is the 1st captured group
- `\(` - is found in the 1st captured group and looks for "(" in the string
- `?` - I'm not sure what this is but I think that it marks the end of the 1st captured group?
- `\d{3}` - looks for digits (numbers) but in sequence of 3 digits
- `(\))` - 2nd captured group and looks for ")" in the string

In conclusion, I am asking for the explanation of `?` and how to return no match if `(345` or `345)` is tested.

Comment: ? - means that previous symbol is not obligatory

Comment: `?` means "zero or one of the previous token". So `(\()?` will match either `"("`, or `""`(an empty string).

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: And why not just do: `^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})$` -- this is saying: `"(ddd)" OR "ddd"` (where `d` is any digit).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to capture the parenthesis?

Comment: I'm learning more about RegExp and there's FreeCodeCamp challenge. But I just wanted to understand how to make the area code work with or without parenthesis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` makes the immediately preceding token in the regex optional. 
You should take it out to force the parenthesis, but since you also need to match the area code without parenthesis, you can specify an OR case using `|`.

The resulting regex looks like

`^((\()\d{3}(\))|\d{3})$`.

Which you can simplify if you don't need to capture the parenthesis themselves to:

`^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})$`

```js
let r = /^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})$/

console.log(r.test('555')) // true
console.log(r.test('(555)')) // true
console.log(r.test('(555')) // false
console.log(r.test('555)')) // false
```

The reason I put the entire thing in a capturing group is so that independent tests can be added around it, for example, making the area code optional and expecting 7 more digits separated by an optional `-` after the 3rd digit.

```js
let r = /^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/

console.log(r.test('5555555')) // true
console.log(r.test('555-5555')) // true
console.log(r.test('5555555555')) // true
console.log(r.test('(555)5555555')) // true
console.log(r.test('(555)555-5555')) // true
console.log(r.test('(5555555555')) // false
console.log(r.test('555)5555555')) // false
```

Comment: Did you pass the FreeCodeCamp?

Comment: I haven't looked at the challenge so I don't know if it satisfies the requirements. This is just an example of a basic way to detect a phone number with regex, but there's probably a lot more things you could consider adding to make it better (such as country code or extensions). You could also just Google a regex and study it as there's tons of examples online.

Comment: I see thanks! Yeah, I'm using https://regex101.com/ to understand each part of the regex. However, some of the explanations, like the one for the `?` seems more like jargon.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about everything except the character `?` is not used to mark the end of the capture group. It is actually a special quantifier character that says the capture group `(\()` must match zero or more characters.

The best way to solve the bracket issue is with the `OR` operator as Tom suggested

For example:

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})$
```

This will look for a match in both the expressions so you can make sure the have either both brackets or none.

Comment: The question was not about preventing matches on `345`!! It was about forcing either 2 brackets or 0 brackets, not 1 bracket.

Comment: Umm... `345` is just random numbers that I typed in. So I'll have to replace `345` with `\d{3}`, correct?

Comment: @KristinaBressler no I misunderstood. If you replace `345` with `\d{3}` you wont match any 3 number combination. I think your best bet is to do what Tom suggested with the `OR` operator:  `^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})$`

Answer (score 0):

not the most elegant but just combine the two regexes?

```
^(\(\d{3}\))$|^(\d{3})$
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a one of possible solutions

simple regex to test 3 digits wrapped in a ( ), If you delete one of the braket the code return false

```
var str = "(345)"
var patt = /^\(\d{3}\)$/g;
var result = patt.test(str);
console.info(res)
```